# What is the equivalent Scala code for this Imperative coding style?

Tags: scala

Find below the imperative style code:

```
private boolean placePieceOnBoard(Results results, 
                                  ChessLayout chessLayout,
                                  List<ChessPiece> piecesToPlace, 
                                  int pieceIndex, 
                                  int startOffset) {
    if(pieceIndex == piecesToPlace.size()) {
        results.addLayout(chessLayout);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        ChessPiece chessPiece = piecesToPlace.get(pieceIndex);
        int offset = startOffset;
        while(offset < chessLayout.getBoardLength()) {

            int placedOffset = chessLayout.placePieceInNextAvailablePosition(chessPiece, offset);
            if( placedOffset == ChessLayout.NULL_OFFSET ) 
                break;
            else {
                logger.debug("piece {} ({}) moved", pieceIndex, chessPiece);

                placePieceOnBoard(results, chessLayout.clone(), piecesToPlace, pieceIndex + 1, placedOffset + 1);

                chessLayout.removeChessPiece(chessPiece);
                offset = placedOffset + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here I am interested in knowing how to convert changes made to offset within the loop in a functional way, how to do early break from the loop etc.

Comment: How Results and ChessLayout look like?

Comment: Please convert your code snippet to Scala first, that is the least you could do! In functional programming, you don't break, you let the function terminate/return. The strategy would have to create a function that takes an offset as a parameter and returns the new offset value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice demonstration of one of Scala's great strengths - gradual, easy migration from imperative Java code to functional code.

To convert to Scala, you don't need to go 100% functional straight away.  You can easily convert what you have to Scala as follows:

```
def placePieceOnBoard(results: Results, 
                      chessLayout: ChessLayout,
                      piecesToPlace: List[ChessPiece], 
                      pieceIndex: Int, 
                      startOffset: Int) {
    if (pieceIndex == piecesToPlace.size()) {
        results.addLayout(chessLayout)
        true
    }
    else {
        val chessPiece = piecesToPlace.get(pieceIndex)
        var offset = startOffset
        while(offset < chessLayout.getBoardLength) {

            val placedOffset = chessLayout.placePieceInNextAvailablePosition(chessPiece, offset)
            if( placedOffset == ChessLayout.NULL_OFFSET ) 
                break
            else {
                logger.debug("piece {} ({}) moved", pieceIndex, chessPiece)

                placePieceOnBoard(results, chessLayout.clone(), piecesToPlace, pieceIndex + 1, placedOffset + 1)

                chessLayout.removeChessPiece(chessPiece)
                offset = placedOffset + 1
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

Note we already have some small improvements in verbosity: no more `;`s, no redundant type signatures, mutable variables converted to constants where possible, eliminated return statements and function brackets.  Note I changed the argument type of `piecesToPlace` to a scala list, you'll need to use the [scala-java converters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$) at the call site to make this compile.

Next, we can start making this more functional... however, this function probably isn't the place you should start, as you are calling state-mutating functions in several places.  For example, you could start with ChessLayout:

```
chessLayout.removeChessPiece(chessPiece)

val placedOffset = chessLayout.placePieceInNextAvailablePosition(chessPiece, offset)
```

These methods mutate ChessLayout, which is not functional style.   You could modify `removeChessPiece` to return a new `ChessLayout` with the piece removed, and `placePieceInNextAvailablePosition` could return a tuple of `(ChessLayout, Int)`.  Once you have stopped any functions called from `placePieceOnBoard` from mutating state, you can then convert it to functional style.